# Commands not all working in J2ME app

Tags: java-me

Part of my j2me project involves use of the filesystem, so I'm starting with a simple file browser. The current issue I'm facing is the implementation of the command processor. To wit:

```
<CODE>

public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
    if (c.getLabel().equals("Exit")) {
        notifyDestroyed();
    }

    // File retrieval code (or call to it) to go here later.

    if (c.getLabel().equals("Enter")) {

        current_name = getRidOfTrailingSlash(current_name)
                          + "/" + mainscreen.getString(mainscreen.getSelectedIndex());
        //                    + "/" + "MemoryCard/";
        System.exit(0);
        if (! setName(current_name)) {
            dirlist = rootlist;
            current_name = "/";
        }

        showDirs();
    }


    if (c.getLabel().equals("Up Dir")) {
       if (current_name.equals("/")) return;
       current_name = getRidOfTrailingSlash(current_name);

       if (setName(current_name)) current_name = current_fc.getPath();
       else                       current_name = "/";

       if (current_name.equals("/")) dirlist = rootlist;
       else {
           try  {
               dirlist = current_fc.list();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {}
       }

       showDirs();
    }


    if (c.getLabel().equals("Create")) {
        System.exit(1);
        // Create code to be added later
    }


    if (c.getLabel().equals("Delete")) {
        System.exit(2);
        // Delete code to be added later
    }


}    // End of command actions
</CODE>
```

I am working on debugging the code for "Enter", and plan to write the code for "Create" and "Delete" at a later date. So for now I have them exit to an expected Security exception.

The code that sets up the commands is as follows:

```
<CODE>
    public String getRidOfTrailingSlash(String s) {
        if (s.equals("/")) return "";
        int len = s.length();
        String end = s.substring(len - 1);
        if (end.equals("/")) s = s.substring(len - 2);
        return s;
    }



    public List makeFileList(Enumeration names, String[] cmds) {
        int i,s,cmdtype;
        String c;

        List l = new List(current_name, List.EXCLUSIVE);
        while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
             c = (String) names.nextElement();
             l.append(c, null);
        }

        s = cmds.length;
        for (i=0; i<s; i++) {
            c = cmds[i];
            if (c.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
                cmdtype = Command.EXIT;
            } else
            if (c.equalsIgnoreCase("Up Dir")) {
                cmdtype = Command.BACK;
            } else {
                cmdtype = Command.BACK;
            }

// I've also tried using ITEM, OK, and one or two other
// command types for the default. Same effect.

            l.addCommand(new Command(c, cmdtype, 1));
        }

        return l;
    }


    private void showDirs() {
        String commands[] = { "Enter", "Up Dir", "Create", "Delete", "Exit" };
        mainscreen = makeFileList(dirlist, commands);
        mainscreen.setCommandListener(this);
        Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(mainscreen);
    }

</CODE>
```

My current issue is that the commands are not all being executed. "Exit" and "Up Dir" are working properly. However, the other three commands don't function at all in the Emulator. They show up in the menus, but selecting them does absolutely nothing when they should be routing the program flow through the System.exit() calls. If I select any of these any number of times, "Up Dir" and "Exit" still work afterward. Furthermore, the select function in the file list doesn't do anything either.

On the phone that I'm writing this for (An LG Rumor Reflex), the select function (checking and unchecking items in the list) *works*, as do the commands "Create", "Delete", "Up Dir", and "Exit". However, the "Enter" command doesn't even appear in the menu!

What am I doing wrong, and why the different behavior on the phone versus the Emulator?

Comment: Have you tried assigning a different cmdtype for each Command?

Comment: Unfortunately there are not that many cmdtypes to go around. I'll see what I can come up with. I've also gotten someone else's code to work in the phone though not the emulator. They use the form Command CMD_X = new Command(params); and if (c == CMD_X) instead of the way I'd been doing it.

Comment: I've changed the format of the commands to the if (c == CMD) method, and have all commands working - again in the phone but NOT in the Emulator. The emulator upon receiving the Open (formally Enter) command asks (again!) if it's okay to read the filesystem then upon selecting Yes locks up. The phone is descending directories like it's supposed to though I have to iron out a few kinks in the ascend directories function.

Comment: Some phones will also ask for permission every time you read the file system. If you can, read each directory only once and keep the result listing in memory.